# 2023 - How do I use the Minecraft/server module to create chat commands?

Tags: javascript, api, minecraft

I am new to JavaScript, but have been using C# for a while, and I decided to write a Minecraft mod to enable some basic Chat Commands. I have researched relentlessly, and tried my hand but error after error persisted. I noticed the API wasn’t auto filling for ANY of the imported classes from the server. I keep getting “Not a function” errors no matter what I try to do. I even tried using the sample script directly from the Microsoft Docs for Minecraft, and the error persists.

Folder Structure

- My BP -

  - scripts -

    - index.js -
  - manifest.json -
  - pack_icon.png -

MANIFEST

```
{
    "format_version": 2,
    "header": {
        "name": "Custom Commands",
        "description": "Custom Commands using the Script API",
        "uuid": "c8c3239f-027f-4e80-890f-880eba65027d",
        "min_engine_version": [1, 19, 40],
        "version": [1, 0, 0]
    },
    "modules": [
        {
            "description": "Behavior Pack Module",
            "type": "data",
            "uuid": "cd2cd41a-1849-410e-8f0a-5d30fde4bd9a",
            "version": [1, 0, 0]
        },
        {
            "description": "Gametest Module",
            "type": "script",
            "language": "javascript",
            "entry": "scripts/index.js",
            "uuid": "f626740d-50a6-49f1-a24a-834983b72134",
            "version": [1, 0, 0]
        }
    ],
    "dependencies": [
        {
            // Minecraft native module - needed to use the "@minecraft/server" module
             
"module_name": "@minecraft/server",
            "version": "1.1.0-beta"
        }
  ]
}
```

INDEX

```
import { world } from '@minecraft/server';

world.events.beforeChat.subscribe(async (eventData) => {
    const player = eventData.sender;
    switch (eventData.message) {
        case '!gmc':
            eventData.cancel = true;
            await player.runCommandAsync('gamemode c');
            break;
        case '!gms':
            eventData.cancel = true;
            await player.runCommandAsync('gamemode s');
            break;
        default: break;
    }
});
```

Comment: The API has changed quite a bit throughout the past few updates, so try setting `min_engine_version` to the latest version. (`[1, 19, 70]`). Also, [this question might be more appropriate for Game Development SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354760/)

Comment: I would just like to say that I hit that flag by accident and I’m not sure how to take it back now. I don’t know if it’s a good flag, a bad flag, or what but it looked like an upvote then I noticed it wasn’t.